# Haskell - Comparing different items with one another within a list

Tags: haskell, recursion

New to haskell (or functional programming languages in general), so it's still hard for me to translate the logic within my head to actual code.

Given the following

```
data User = User String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Task = Task String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Command =
    Add User
  | Create Task
  | Allow (User, Task)
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I want to make sure that every Allow has a User that has already been Added. The above logic will be defined in a function Verified :: [Command] -> Bool

```
example = [
    Add (User "Michael"),
    Create (Task "Laundry"),
    Allow (User "Michael", Task "Laundry")
  ]

Verified example -- Return True

example2 = [
    Add (User "Michael"),
    Create (Task "Laundry"),
    Allow (User "Bob", Task "Laundry")
  ]

Verified example2 -- Return False
```

Below is my thought process, if you can help me translate that into code / refine my thoughts I would really appreciate it

1. Reverse the list of commands. If I see an Allow with a User and Task, then it must be true that somewhere down the list, there is an Add with that specific user. Otherwise, return false.
2. Use elem within Prelude  to see if such Add does exist within the commands or not (I am thinking recursion).

Right now I have only been able to successfully created a simple function that reverse the list,

```
reverseList :: [Command] -> [Command]
reverseList [] = []
reverseList (x:xs) = (reverse xs) ++ [x]
```

but aside from that I don't really know where to begin implementing verified :: [Command] -> Bool

Edit: Just found out that Haskell has a built-in reverse function, guess my reverseList won't be put to use anymore

Comment: Note that `reverseList (x:xs) = (reverse xs) ++ [x]` is a pretty bad idea (n^2 complexity).

Comment: yeah interestingly I was just reading an article on how that is a bad way to implement the reverse function. I'll be using the built-in reverse function though!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a list of commands represents a sequence which depends on each previous command to be valid or invalid. That is, `[Add "Bob", Allow "Bob" ...]` is valid, while `[Allow "Bob" ..., Add "Bob"]`.

In this case, the simplest way to do this is probably to reverse the list, and iterate through it; if you find an `Allow`, insert it into the set of `Add`s which you must find; if you find an `Add`, remove it from the set of `Add`s which you must find. Then, once you reach the empty list, if your set is not empty, you have found that the command sequence is not valid.

You can use a list to represent the set, but it would be easier to use `Data.Set.Set`, which already has the insert and remove (called delete) functions defined.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

verify :: [Command] -> Bool
verify = go S.empty . reverse where 

  go :: S.Set User -> [Command] -> Bool
  go s [] = error "TODO"
  go s (x:xs) = case x of 
                  Create {}    -> go s xs 
                  Add    u     -> error "TODO"
                  Allow (u, _) -> error "TODO"
```

You could use a fold, but writing it using primitive recursion is probably enlightening.

For this to work, you'll need to also derive `Ord` for `User`:

```
 newtype User = User String deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
```

Solution (ps give me spoiler tags stack overflow):

```
Scroll right >                                                                                                                                                                                          go :: S.Set User -> [Command] -> Bool
                                                                                                                                                                                                        go s [] = S.null s 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        go s (x:xs) = case x of 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Create {}    -> go s xs 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Add    u     -> go (S.delete u s) xs 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Allow (u, _) -> go (S.insert u s) xs
```

Comment: Odd, I can do a spoiler block of code and it previews correctly while editing, but checking in an incognito window of my browser shows me that that the spoiler tag does not appear to work after the edit is made.  I might report this as a bug on meta.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

First import `reverse` from `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List (reverse)
```

Define `verify` to apply `verifyBackwards` on the reverse of the command list:

```
verify :: [Command] -> Bool
verify cmds = verifyBackwards (reverse cmds)
```

`verifyBackwards` would then call `verifyElem` for every element along with the rest of the reversed command list (i.e. the elements before that element in the original list) `and`ing the result with a recursive call to `verifyBackwards` to verify the rest of the elements:

```
verifyBackwards :: [Command] -> Bool
verifyBackwards [] = True
verifyBackwards (x:xs) = verifyElem x xs && verifyBackwards xs
```

Finally `verifyElem` would return `True` for all commands except the `Allow` command. For the `Allow` command, it would check that a user is `Add`ed before being `Allow`ed:

```
verifyElem :: Command -> [Command] -> Bool
verifyElem (Allow (User u, _)) xs = elem (Add (User u)) xs
verifyElem _ _ = True
```